# How to reply to your boss when asks when your colleague is coming to work?

Tags: communication

Your boss comes into your office (which is shared with a few other colleagues) and wants to talk with one of your colleagues, which is not in yet (this is in the morning). Your boss asks when your colleague usually comes in and looks at you. How do you answer this question if you don't feel comfortable answering this question and you may know the answer?

Comment: Other than looking at his desk and saying "9am [substitute for the median arrival time that he comes in, Hint: it's on his contract]"??

Comment: Is your colleague late? Will they be coming in late without permission?

Comment: You just tell what you know?

Comment: I simply say "Sorry, I don't know.".

Answer (score 10):

> How do you answer this question?

Well, **if you do have a good idea** on the time your coworker usually arrives then you **answer giving an estimate around that time**.

**If you don't** have a good idea, or you don't want to compromise your coworker or perhaps get into an uncomfortable situation, you should answer honestly and say something like, *"To be honest boss, I am not sure. He is usually on time so he surely won't take long to come now."*

Comment: Another useful phrase is: "I haven't honestly been paying attention to that."

Comment: @HLGEM yes, also another option that is not compromising to say